# How do i access full dataset in flume-to-kafka pipeline?

Tags: apache-kafka, flume

I am reading a text file SMSSpamCollection as a flume-source, posting it to kafka topic which is a flume-sink.

```
     # Agent Name:
     a1.sources = r1
     a1.sinks = sample
     a1.channels = sample-channel


     # Source configuration:
     a1.sources.r1.type = exec
     a1.sources.r1.command = tail -f /Users/val/Documents/code/spark/m11_to_Upload/SMSSpamCollection
     a1.sources.r1.logStdErr = true

     # Sink type
     #a1.sinks.sample.type = logger

     # Buffers events in memory to channel
     a1.channels.sample-channel.type = memory
     a1.channels.sample-channel.capacity = 1000
     a1.channels.sample-channel.transactionCapacity = 100

     # Bind the source and sink to the channel
     a1.sources.r1.channels.selector.type = replicating
     a1.sources.r1.channels = sample-channel

     # Related settings Kafka, topic, and host channel where it set the source
     a1.sinks.sample.type = org.apache.flume.sink.kafka.KafkaSink
     a1.sinks.sample.topic = sample_topic
     a1.sinks.sample.brokerList = 127.0.0.1:9092
     a1.sinks.sample.requiredAcks = 1
     a1.sinks.sample.batchSize = 20
     a1.sinks.sample.channel = sample-channel
```

I use this command

```
    flume-ng agent --conf conf --conf-file /usr/local/Cellar/flume/1.9.0/libexec/conf/flume-sample.conf  -Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG,console --name a1 -Xmx512m -Xms256m
```

When I read data from kafka topic

```
    kafka-console-consumer --topic sample_topic --from-beginning --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
```

I see only last 10 records from original file.

```
    ham Ok lor... Sony ericsson salesman... I ask shuhui then she say quite gd 2 use so i considering...
    ham Ard 6 like dat lor.
    ham Why don't you wait 'til at least wednesday to see if you get your .
    ham Huh y lei...
    spam    REMINDER FROM O2: To get 2.50 pounds free call credit and details of great offers pls reply 2 this text with your valid name, house no and postcode
    spam    This is the 2nd time we have tried 2 contact u. U have won the £750 Pound prize. 2 claim is easy, call 087187272008 NOW1! Only 10p per minute. BT-national-rate.
    ham Will ü b going to esplanade fr home?
    ham Pity, * was in mood for that. So...any other suggestions?
    ham The guy did some bitching but I acted like i'd be interested in buying something else next week and he gave it to us for free
    ham Rofl. Its true to its name
```

What is the proper way to see all the records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `tail` which by default shows the last 10 lines of a file.

Instead use:

```
a1.sources.r1.command = tail -c +0 -f /Users/val/Documents/code/spark/m11_to_Upload/SMSSpamCollection
```

The `-c +0` tells `tail` to start from the first character of the file.

BTW an alternative is to use Kafka Connect with something like the [Spooldir](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-spooldir/index.html) or [File Pulse](https://github.com/streamthoughts/kafka-connect-file-pulse) plugin.

Comment: It worked in console, but when I open a stream inside spark streaming app, I get empty output. Any idea on how to answer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59236297/how-do-i-consume-kafka-topic-inside-spark-streaming-app) ?